# Setting the Toolbar title in a Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog, android-toolbar

I have created a `Dialog` with a custom layout that allows me to display a `ListView` with custom objects inside of the dialog. I also added a `Toolbar` (`android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`) to the `Dialog` to give it a little more substance. I am trying to figure out how to set the title for the `Toolbar`, but I have been having some issues. Usually I would do something like the following:

```
myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);            
setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
```

However, I cannot use this in the class that I have created to build the `Dialog` because `setSupportActionBar` is an `ActionBarActivity` method. I have also tried to use `setTitle` to specify the title text, to no avail.

So, what is the best way to set the `Toolbar` title without using any of the `ActionBarActivity` methods? My code is shown below:

**`Dialog` layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/dialog_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/group_listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:divider="@color/grey_300"
        android:dividerHeight="1dip"
        android:fadingEdge="none">
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnHolderLL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_ok_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingRight="1dp"
            android:paddingLeft="1dp"
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:text="Ok"
            android:clickable="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**`Dialog` builder class**

```
public class ListGroup
{
    public static Dialog CreateGroupDialog(Context context, ArrayList<ListObject> arrayList)
    {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.dialogTheme);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.group_dialog);
        Button dialogButton = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_ok_button);
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = li.inflate(R.layout.group_dialog, null);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_toolbar);
        // The following line has no effect...
        toolbar.setTitle("List Group");

        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        ListView listView = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.group_listview);
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(context, R.layout.list_object, arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

As an example, I would then create a `Dialog` like so:

```
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList<ListObject>();
ListObject listObject1 = new ListObject("Item #1", new String[]{""}, "", "", "", "blank",
        "blank", "blank", "blank", "blank", "blank", "", 1, false, 0, 0, false, false, null, null);
ListObject listObject2 = new ListObject("Item #2", new String[]{""}, "", "", "", "blank",
        "blank", "blank", "blank", "blank", "blank", "", 1, false, 0, 0, false, false, null, null);
ListObject listObject3 = new ListObject("Item #3", new String[]{""}, "", "", "", "blank",
        "blank", "blank", "blank", "blank", "blank", "", 1, false, 0, 0, false, false, null, null);
arrayList.add(listObject1);
arrayList.add(listObject2);
arrayList.add(listObject3);
Dialog groupDialog = ListGroup.CreateGroupDialog(MainActivity.this, null, arrayList);
groupDialog.show();
```

This creates the `Dialog` shown below; as you can see, there is no title...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use

```
 LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
 View view = li.inflate(R.layout.group_dialog, null);
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_toolbar);
```

You are inflating a new layout and referencing a new `Toolbar`, rather than using the one your dialog uses (which you inflated in `dialog.setContentView(R.layout.group_dialog);`). Similarly to how you got a reference to the `Button` in your dialog, you should retrieve the Toolbar by using:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_toolbar);
```

Comment: An oversight on my part. Thank, this is exactly what I needed.